# Need to extract values from a dataframe and convert to a string and create a for loop that adds the random x and y to the end of each item

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a excel(csv) file and a text file(txt) and I need to extract x and y from random rows from the column headings X and Y. This I am told needs to be converted to a string so that I can then have the text file containing a list of objects to then generate random objects and a random x and y.

In other words, something like the following (Final Output):

Object 1 was sent at coordinates x and y.

I need to generate a random Object 2, 5, 8, 1, etc along with a random x but the same y for that particular row where the x is in the excel file. This needs to generate 5000 random Objects # and random x but its associated y.

Note the objects must repeat for I have 149 and the same goes for the x and y although I have 10,000. Just need a random generator

Goal:

- Object 13 was sent at x and y.
- Object 101 was sent at x and y.
- Object 57 was sent at x and y.
- Object 101 was sent at x and y.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample_points = pd.read_csv("pointssample.csv")
sample_points
```

[image]

```
# opening the file in read mode
my_file = open("objects.txt", "r")
my_file

# reading the file
data = my_file.read()

# replacing end of line('/n') with ' ' and
# splitting the text it further when '.' is seen.
data_into_list = data.split('\n')
data_into_list

xypoints = sample_points[['X', 'Y']]
xypoints
```

[image]

```
sample1 = xypoints.sample(n=1)
sample1
```

[image]

```
type(sample1)
```

[image]`

Comment: I've had a go at tidying this question up, but I'm struggling to figure out what you're asking.  The number of images are slightly disturbing as well, couldn't these just be entered as plain text?  see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1358308 for info about why images shouldn't be used by default